# What is the meaning of download property in ionic 4 ion-button?

Tags: ionic4

I would like to implement a download button in a web app developed with ionic 4. I read that I can add a download property in ion-button

> > Download: This attribute instructs browsers to download a URL instead of navigating to it, so the user will be prompted to save it as a local file. If the attribute has a value, it is used as the pre-filled file name in the Save prompt (the user can still change the file name if they want).

It seems that the attribute will be the file name in the save prompt, so my question is where to put the download url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ion-button download="MyFavicon" href="/assets/icon/favicon.png">My Icon</ion-button>
```

Based on what I could find in the Ionic docs and was able to test out, the download attribute seems to work exactly like the anchor tag download attribute. I found this in the ion-button [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button) regarding the href property:

> Contains a URL or a URL fragment that the hyperlink points to. If this property is set, an anchor tag will be rendered.

Seems like the ion-button with an href property renders as an anchor tag which can then use the download attribute. During testing I was only able to download images within my app's domain. I'm guessing its a cross-origin thing.

Hope this helps.